# Data is present in both the table but Not able to get the data using subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have table_A and Table_B and am getting data(A_B C_D) from Table B and using the same data am not able to get any record from table A. Though the same
 data(A_B C_D) is available in Table A using SubQueries.

```
VALUE: A_B C_D
Column_A: A_B C_D
```

But still am not getting any record in TABLE_A
I used trim function then also I not getting any record.

QUERY:

```
select * from Table_A 
where column_A in (select distinct value from table_b where column_B=2);
```

Comment: Check for null values or letter cases?

Comment: No null values are present and all are in upper case.

Comment: sub statement returns any values?

Comment: Post column types / DDL

Comment: subquery returns the O/P: A_B C_D

Comment: It's really hard to say without any more info